# How hard would it be to write this shader? Multipoint shadow lighting

Tags: c++, shader, glew

So, I have a simple project right now.  Basically its just a bunch of cuboids that are all axis alligned... so it has really simple geometry.

Anyway I am considering adding a better shader to it.  Currently I am using the "flat shader" that is a stock shader in GLShaderManager.  It is coloring everything with a flat color.  However I would love if I could build a shader like the following.

Basically I want a shader that has an array of point lights at various positions with varying intensities.
Probably defined like this.

```
struct Light {
float x;
float y;
float z;
float intensity;
};

Light Lighting[20];
```

And basically based on the level geometry and lights, I would love to simulate basic lighting and shadows, also it would be cool to have a circle under the player (like the player is actually their).

How hard would this be to make?  How would I pass it my level geometry and light array. (note even though each cuboid is its own QUADS batch it will be easy to make any kind of variable that stores the data).

I am using Glew, GLTools, GLShaderManager, GLBatch, visual studio 2010, probably whatever "GSHL".

If you could just let me know how complicated a shader like this would be let me know.  Also if it is easy to find a shader that works like this online if you could link it.

Also what are the difference between the two types of shaders? (Vertex, and fragment).

Comment: It is unclear if you are asking "how hard?" or "how to?". If the first, then the question is not useful (a valid answer could be "quite hard"). If the second, then the question is too broad. Personally it seems like you need to improve your theory and understanding. Lighting and shadows is not as simple as passing geometry, and are two of the hardest topics in real time rendering. I would recommend a good book, for example game engine architecture, 2nd edition. For a very quick answer, based on what you have described that you have achieved so far, I believe, it probably will be "quite hard".

Comment: This book? http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Second-Edition/dp/1466560010???  I have that book somewhere in my house... I dont remember it having much example code just talking about general concepts.

Comment: yep that's the one. Its the best intro to game engine development in a single book IMO.

Comment: Also, if you feel you are beginner at graphics APIs and rendering in general, then you should probably also either get the latest openGL superbible, or the latest Luna directx book. Those will teach you all the basics about shaders and rendering techniques for the graphics API you have chosen. They are easy to approach and very beginner friendly. You would ideally read both. If you feel your math isnt strong enough, then I would also recommend 3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development by Dunn and Parberry. For a survey of graphics techniques (advanced), real time rendering 3rd ed.

Comment: By "ideally read both" I was referring to one graphics api book and game engine architecture together. I didnt mean read both a directx and opengl API book. The modern versions of graphics APIs (dx10-11 and opengl 3-4) share fairly similar concepts, just with different API topologies. Be aware that there are incoming technologies such as dx12 and vulkan (new openGL based on AMD's mantle) which are a lot closer to hardware, and are realistically intended for commercial or heavyweight applications (AAA games) rather than replacing their older versions.

Comment: ...And, as a final comment, if you are already on windows and using visual studio, then you will probably have less headaches working with directx11. I know this advice might not be what you are looking for, but the resources, documentation and built in tools with the directx SDK far surpasses openGL support. For example, if you grab visual studio 2013 community edition, you will get a built in graphics debugger (even though options like NSight and renderdoc exist). I completely understand if you are targeting cross platform or want to stick to OpenGL though etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's relatively simple, but the thing about modern GL is that the initial learning curve is quite steep. At first it seems like you have to roll up your sleeves and learn how to do everything (essentially true) but later, it starts to seem like it made things easier than ever before with much more predictable behaviors since you're in the driver's seat.

One of the first things you want to learn to do is understand how to specify attributes from CPU to GPU. For attributes which don't vary on a per-vertex or per-fragment basis such as your light positions and intensities, you want uniform attributes. Check out examples utilizing the `glUniform*` functions to see how to do this. This will allow you to then experiment, passing values from the CPU side to the GPU side and then seeing how they affect the shader to accelerate your learning.

After that, it's worth learning how direct lighting is computed given a ray bouncing off a surface with phong shading, separating ambient, diffuse, and specular terms.

Later you might even want to store this light data into an environment map. That'll give you the ability to use as many lights as you want without affecting the speed of the shader.

About vertex vs. fragment shaders, vertex shaders compute things on a vertex-by-vertex basis, including data for the fragment shader to then use. The fragment shader is kind of like a pixel shader (in HLSL, it's actually just called a 'pixel shader'). It deals with rasterizing what's in between those vertices and is operating on a pixel-by-pixel basis (however with some potential overdraw). Often for lighting, the real heart of the logic will be in the fragment shader, while the vertex shader serves as an intermediary step to compute all the relevant values for the fragment shader to interpolate and use. The vertex shader is part of the 3D geometry pipeline, while the fragment shader is part of 2D rasterization.

It shouldn't take too long or be too hard to get the hang of this, but you want to approach this kind of slowly and in babysteps. There's a lot of setup work involved in establishing a lighting/shading pipeline for your software with the precise characteristics you want, and for the final work, you want to kind of plan ahead. So it's good to establish a separate scrap project and start experimenting away to figure out how things work.

Comment: Thankyou so much! This is really helpful to hear.  My current jam is that I am hoping to be done by next Saturday.  However I have a lot of time in a day I can spend on it.   My main problem is that I don't know exactly where to learn all of this stuff.  What is a good source?  I am currently using GLSuperbible 2006 or something.  The problem is it is really outdated  and doesn't really cover this.

Comment: question how do you pass values in and out of a shader?  For example this call here "shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBlue);" passes it a color.  What does this look like in the vertex and fragment shaders?

Comment: @Andrew To pass data around, you want to look into uniform attributes, vertex attributes (`in` parameters), and to get data from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, output attributes (`out` parameters).

Comment: @Andrew As for learning material, try this: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/?intro. Try not to skip parts even though I know you're in a hurry. It's a bit too easy to get lost with GLSL if you don't take the time to understand the pipeline.

Comment: hey do you know how one might create a hud in glew?  I am sorry to take advantage of your kindness by asking another question.